# How to make sure GDAL Java binding doesn't crash my whole application?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, java

I'm using GDAL Java binding  to convert some files (ogr2ogr), such as shapefile to GeoJSON. The problem is when something goes wrong it crashes the whole application and I have to start it up again. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: maybe use GeoTools as it's all Java

Comment: Is it possible to convert dxf to GeoJson with GeoTools?